# Nativescript: Show ActivityIndicator while page transition is in progress

Tags: events, navigation, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm using Nativescript + Typescript/Angular2.

I have a page that is pretty heavy to load (it contains a tabview and a map) so I would like to show an ActivityIndicator when the routerlink of the referral page is tapped and hide it when the page is loaded. I guess I might leverage the `load` event of the `Page` class (as mentioned [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/page#attaching-event-handler-for-the-page-loaded-event-to-set-bindingcontext)) in order to achieve it, but in the documentation it's not clear of how to do it in Angular Nativescript. Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am looking for the same, but with `nativescript-vue`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the page for which you want to show ActivityIndicator  and add at the top :

```
<ActivityIndicator [busy]="isLoading" [visibility]="isLoading ? 'visible' : 'collapse'" row="1" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"></ActivityIndicator>
```

you will have to create a new property named isLoading in the component for this page  and initialize it to false :

```
isLoading = false;
```

Now that you have this property the final step would be to set this property to true when your data is loading to show the loader.This will vary as per your implementation. But for the sake of explanation we can consider you have written some service that will handle fetching of data and we are subscribing to it in our component. For which i will make use of ngOnInit() function to subscribe to this service  and show the activityIndicator as follows

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.isLoading = true; //setting isLoading to true in order to show the loader
  this.SomeService.load()
    .subscribe(res => {
      //do stuff with the data 
      //like iterate ,bind etc 
      this.isLoading = false; // setting the isLoading property back to false after doing req. stuff.
    });
}
```

and that's it . I hope this will help you.

Comment: The problem is exactly the implementation and what to bind the isLoading property too. 
Unfortunately I don't need to hook the spinner to any sort of data loading begin/end,  or external service async activity, but to the page loading and rendering itself. So I guess, the ngOnInit() lifecycle is useless in this case, because it's triggered by the Angular Component after initialization is is already done.

Comment: Let me try to explain it better: I need to show the loading after a page transition from page A to page B  is triggered  (when the user taps on a listitem on page ) and until the page transition is completed. 
Just the time for the platform to resolve the routing entry and put the new page in the frame. 
So the spinner will be likely shown while the user is still viewing the page A